# objective C for-loop break and continue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, for-loop

How can i use a 'break' statement within a for-loop which continues form a specified label?

ex;

```
outer: for(int i = 0;i<[arABFBmatches count];i++){
    for(int i = 0;i<[arABFBmatches count];i++){
        //
        break _____;
    }
}
```

How to break to outer?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Hard to say from your question.  I'd interpret it that you want to skip the rest of the iterations of the inner loop and continue the outer loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < [arABFBmatches count]; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < [arABFBmatches count]; j++) {
        if (should_skip_rest)
            break; // let outer loop continue iterating
    }
}
```

Note that I changed the name of your inner loop invariant;  using `i` in both is inviting insanity.

If you want to break from both loops, I wouldn't use a goto.  I'd do:

```
BOOL allDoneNow = NO;
for (int i = 0; i < [arABFBmatches count]; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < [arABFBmatches count]; j++) {
        if (should_skip_rest) {
            allDoneNow = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (allDoneNow) break;
}
```

Comment: And please, for the sake of readability, let us not forget to put spaces around our operators.  Not "for(int i = 0;i<[arABFBmatches count];i++)". Instead: "for (int i = 0; i < [arABFBmatches count]; i++)"

Answer (score 12):

Roughly:

```
for(int i = 0;i<[arABFBmatches count];i++){
    for(int j = 0;j<[arABFBmatches count];j++){
        //
        goto outer_done;
    }
}
outer_done:
```

Objective-C does not have labelled break.

Comment: If you're going to use `goto`, be very very very careful that you handle memory management properly.

Comment: `goto` is better than setting a flag and testing the flag to tell whether to break out of the outer loop. sure we must be careful.

Comment: Not necessarily better at all; if the inner loop is surrounded by some setup/teardown logic, the `goto` may happily jump right over the teardown.  If you have to add this kind of logic later, it is easy to forget the short circuit case when refactoring.   There is a strong argument to be made for control-flow that is jumpless.

Comment: I think that the use of "goto" should be avoided. Apart from bbum's excellent reason, it also hurts readability of the code.

Answer (score 3):

```
BOOL done = NO;
for(int i = 0;i<[arABFBmatches count] && !done; i++)
{
    for(int i = 0;i<[arABFBmatches count] && !done;i++)
    {
        if (termination condition) 
        {
             // cleanup
             done = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also add an explanation?

Answer (score 3):

From Apple's Objective-C docs:

> Objective-C is defined as a small but powerful set of extensions to
>   the standard ANSI C language.

So break and continue can be used wherever they are permitted in C.

**continue** can be used in looping constructs (for, while and do/while loops).

**break** can be used in those same looping constructs as well as in switch statements.

Answer (score 1):

'break' will only get you out of the innermost loop or switch. You can use 'return' to exit out of a function at any time.Please have a look  at the [this](https://discussions.apple.com/message/10099595#10099595) link.

Comment: Most commercial design rules demand only one (1) 'return' from a function.